# Keras (Hidden) Layer Setup Causing Issues

Tags: deep-learning, keras

EDIT: This appears to have solved itself. I’ll spend some more time on it then delete this post if it still works well. Thanks.

I have a network that works fine if I use only 1 hidden layer, and gives nonsense results if I use more than that. I looked into it and found I should add an input layer, but now with the input layer the network never learns as it should. What am I doing wrong?

"Working" code with 1 hidden layer:

```
def make_model(hidden_layers, units, activ = ‘relu’):
  new_model = Sequential()
        
  for layer in range(hidden_layers):
    new_model.add(Dense(units = units,
                        activation = activ,
                        kernel_initializer = keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0, stddev = 0.05),
                        bias_initializer = keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0, stddev = 0.05)))

  new_model.add(Dense(units = 1,
                      activation = 'sigmoid',
                      kernel_initializer = keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0, stddev = 0.05),
                      bias_initializer = keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0, stddev = 0.05)))

  new_model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

  return new_model
```

Nonsense code no matter how many hidden layers:

```
def make_model(hidden_layers, units, activ = ‘relu’, input_dim):
  new_model = Sequential()

  new_model.add(Dense(units=units,
                  activation=activ,
                  kernel_initializer = keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0, stddev = 0.05),
                  bias_initializer = keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0, stddev = 0.05),
                  input_dim = input_dim))
        
  for layer in range(hidden_layers):
    new_model.add(Dense(units = units,
                        activation = activ,
                        kernel_initializer = keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0, stddev = 0.05),
                        bias_initializer = keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0, stddev = 0.05)))

  new_model.add(Dense(units = 1,
                      activation = 'sigmoid',
                      kernel_initializer = keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0, stddev = 0.05),
                      bias_initializer = keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0, stddev = 0.05)))

  new_model.compile(optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

  return new_model
```

Thanks!

Comment: So in the first example you call `make_model` with `hidden_layers=1` and the loop just executes once, correct? Also can you tell us which activation function are you using?

Comment: Yup! One loop execution. 

I’ve been using relu!

Comment: Ok, so could you change the weight initialization to `he_uniform` and see what happens? Maybe also lower the LR a bit, like 1e-3.